# Cognito User Pools is returning null user object

Tags: amazon-web-services, object, authentication, null, amazon-cognito

Folks, I am getting similar error where my getCurrentUser is returning null. I think, I partially know the reason for the same.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.7.16.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/web/amazon-cognito-identity.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/web/aws-cognito-sdk.js"></script>

    import * as AWSCognito from 'amazon-cognito-identity';

const region = 'us-east-1';
const docClient = createDynamoDbClient();

function createDynamoDbClient() {

    AWS.config.update({
    region: "us-east-1",    endpoint: 'https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'});

    userAuth();

  return new AWS.DynamoDB();
}

function userAuth() {
  var data = {
        UserPoolId: '***********',
        ClientId: '************'
    };

    var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(data);

    var cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();
    try {

        if (cognitoUser != null) 
        {
            cognitoUser.getSession(function(err, session) 
            {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return;
                }

                AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
                AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(
                {
                    IdentityPoolId : 'us-east-1:********', 
                    Logins : {
                        "cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_*******": session.getIdToken().getJwtToken()
                    }
                });   

                AWS.config.credentials.get(function(err) {
                if (!err) 
                {
                    console.log("In try block 4");
                    var id = AWS.config.credentials.identityId;
                    console.log('Cognito Identity ID '+ id);

                    var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient(
                    { 
                        region: AWS.config.region 
                    }
                );

                var params = 
                {
                    TableName: 'VideoInfo',
                    Item:{
                        keyName:kN, 
                        technicalMetadata:tM
                    }
                };

                docClient.put(
                    params,
                    function(err, data) {
                        if (err){ 
                            console.error(err);
                        }else
                        { 
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    }
                );
                }
            });
        });
    } 
    else {
        console.log(cognitoUser);
        return;
    }
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
  return;
}

}
```

I am getting the below error essentially which is causing the complete issue.

TypeError: root.AWSCognito is undefined
ReferenceError: AmazonCognitoIdentity is not defined

Possible, it means I am not getting AWSCognito object itself using which I can get the correct UserPool and ending up with null user.

Spent a lot of time on this today and really appreciate if someone can help on the same!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BH45k.png)

Comment: Any help on this team please!!

Comment: After couple of days going back and forth, I figured out that I should use AWS-SDK itself instead of AWS-Cognito. I can get the id_token from the browser itself instead of using the below code var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(data);

    var cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser(); Not very clean but does the job for the moment :D. Please let me know if you need the updated code and happy to share the same.